# Facebook family relationship Json data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Need help,

```
function getFamily()
{
FB.api('/me/family', function(response) {                   
alert(JSON.stringify(response));                        
});
}
```

With the above function i am unable to fetch the list of family relationship. 
If there is any other way?
Thanks

Comment: It appears to be undocumented so you should better not use it but check this: http://zapumal.info/?p=339 . Probably facebook have removed it from being public i.e. for specific apps only!

Comment: It’s _not_ undocumented, it’s listed under the user objects „Connections” on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: I added the fields as id and name. Still the response is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you acquired "user_relationships" permission first …?

Comment: how do i do that. Please help

Comment: function getFamily()
     {
      FB.api('/me/family',{ fields: 'id'}, function(response) {
       var family_data = JSON.stringify(response);
       alert(family_data);
       
      });
     }

Comment: This throws out a empty response data. Fields as id and name.

Comment: If you don’t know to ask for permissions, please consult the docs.

Comment: See the [Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) docs for a list of permissions, and the Authentication docs for how to authenticate

Comment: I have mentioned those permissions. When we create the APP-> under Auth Dialogue->Authenticated Referrals-> Then user_permissions.

Comment: Authenticated Referrals only work when the user reaches your app via certain ways. Have you made _sure_ the permissions have been given by the user?